# How to execute a function on a thread that is already running?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have thread A that calls FunctionX() every 5 seconds with a timer. But sometimes I need the value of FunctionX() from another thread, thread B, instantly and can't wait for the timer execution. I can't call FunctionX() directly from thread B because it uses some external components that die if called from another thread than the original. So FunctionX() must always run on thread A. How to get the value of FunctionX() on thread B instantly without waiting for the timer to call the function?

Comment: Some kind of producer-consumer pattern, where the timer pushes a value and your direct call pushes it as well, where the FunctionX() pushes its result to another queue?

Comment: Are you familiar with Taskbased asynchronous pattern? You could have a dedicated thread await a blocking queue. You enqueue TaskCompletionSource objects to that queue. On the thread, it will dequue it , call FunctionX and set the CompletionSource Result to the result of the function ... just an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be dependent on the type of timer that you're using, but the [`System.Threading.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) class, as one example, exposes a [`Change`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz1c7148(v=vs.110).aspx) method that you can use to persuade the timer to fire now. Here's an example in a Console application test harness:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace FiringTheTimerTestHarness
{
    class Program
    {
        public static Thread _worker;
        public static Timer _timer;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _worker = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadWorker));
            _worker.Start();
            var startTime = DateTime.Now;
            // Simulate the main UI thread being active doing stuff (i.e. if there's a Windows Forms app so we don't need anything to 
            // keep the app "alive"
            while (1==1)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                if (startTime.AddSeconds(30) < DateTime.Now)
                {
                    // Lets pretend that we need to fire the timer *now* so that we can get the result *now*
                    _timer.Change(0, 5000);
                }
            }
        }

        public static void ThreadWorker()
        {
            _timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(DoStuffEveryFiveSeconds), null, 5000, 5000);
            while (1 == 1)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }

        public static void DoStuffEveryFiveSeconds(object state)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: Doing stuff", DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
}
```

You'll see output that looks something like this:

> 05/09/2017 10:04:44: Doing stuff
>
> 05/09/2017 10:04:49: Doing stuff
>
> 05/09/2017 10:04:54: Doing stuff
>
> 05/09/2017 10:04:59: Doing stuff
>
> 05/09/2017 10:05:04: Doing stuff
>
> 05/09/2017 10:05:09: Doing stuff
>
> 05/09/2017 10:05:09: Doing stuff
>
> 05/09/2017 10:05:09: Doing stuff
>
> 05/09/2017 10:05:09: Doing stuff
>
> 05/09/2017 10:05:09: Doing stuff

So, the timer fires (as intended) every five seconds and then it starts getting fired every 100 milliseconds (i.e. "on demand"). This code *is sat in a contrived test harness* so looks a little odd, but the intent is basically to show you the outcome from calling the `Change` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is **an outline** of what I was talking about in comment. **Completely untested** !!

```
class FunctionXCaller
{
    private Task mTask;
    private BlockingCollection<TaskCompletionSource<TResult>> queue = new BlockingCollection<TaskCompletionSource<TResult>>();

    public FunctionXCaller()
    {
         mTask = Task.Run( () => WorkerMethod );
    }

    private void WorkerMethod()
    {
         while( !queue.IsCompleted )
         {
              TaskCompletionSource<TResult> tcs = queue.take();
              tcs.TrySetResult(FunctionX());
         }
    }


    public Task<TResult> CallXAsync()
    {
         TaskCompletionSource<TResult> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TResult>();
         queue.Add(tcs);
         return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

Beware: As I already wrote, this is just to get you an idea. There is a lot that needs to be added, like shutting down, clean up, exception handling, ...

The idea is you can call `await FunctionXCallerInstance.CallXAsnc()` from any thread and have FunctionX be executed always on the worker thread. Which here would be a ThreadPool Thread.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to easily do this with Microsoft's Reactive Framework (Rx):

```
void Main()
{
    EventLoopScheduler threadA = new EventLoopScheduler();
    IObservable<int> timer = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0), threadA).Select(x => FunctionX());
    IDisposable subscription = timer.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("timer: " + x));
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(12.5));
    int value = Observable.Start(() => FunctionX(), threadA).Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("value: " + value);
}

private int counter = 0;
public int FunctionX()
{
    Console.Write("ManagedThreadId: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + "; ");
    Console.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString("ss.ffff") + "; ");
    return ++counter;
}
```

The output of this test code is this:

```
ManagedThreadId: 13; 47.5655; timer: 1
ManagedThreadId: 13; 52.5601; timer: 2
ManagedThreadId: 13; 55.0649; value: 3
ManagedThreadId: 13; 57.5592; timer: 4
ManagedThreadId: 13; 02.5594; timer: 5
ManagedThreadId: 13; 07.5741; timer: 6
```

Note that the third value is obtained 2.5 seconds between the preceding and subsequent values, and that this is the only value with the tag "value". The others have "timer".

If you need anything else run on `threadA` just do this:

```
threadA.Schedule(() => { /* Do this on `threadA` */ });
```